# 2 HTML canvasses stacked on top of each other, with the top transparent to click events?

Tags: canvas, paperjs

So I am building a small CAD app where I am supposed to have a grid as well.

The grid must be on top of all elements. 
Unfortunately the way I implement UNDO functionality does not allow me to incorporate the grid into the main canvas.

Therefore I have thought of stacking 2 canvasses on top of each other.

- The top grid would be the ''Grid Canvas'', used only for drawing a
  grid.
- The bottom grid would be the ''main canvas'', used for everything
  else.

**Now the issue is that I can stack the 2 canvasses just fine, but the top canvas blocks the click events to the main canvas.**

Is there any solution to this?

I am using [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org) as the library to create the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pointer-events:none
```

On the element you want clicks to 'pass-through'
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: thanks, I thought pointer-events just makes it block mouse-events.